# Turn my mssql query into a structured xml result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Right now I have a simple query that turns my sql results into XML however it does not do it in the way I want it to . This is my query

```
 select top 4 id,email from [user] where len(email) > 5

 for xml raw, ROOT('MyRoot')
```

and this is the result below

```
<MyRoot>
<row id="7" email="test1@gmail.com" />
<row id="8" email="test2@gmail.com" />
<row id="9" email="test3@gmail.com" />
<row id="10" email="test4@gmail.com" />
</MyRoot>
```

I would like to change that result set into this

```
   <MyRoot>
   <row> <id>7</id> <email>test1@gmail.com</email> </row>
   <row  <id>8</id> <email>test2@gmail.com</email> </row>
   <row  <id>9</id> <email>test3@gmail.com</email> </row>
   <row <id>10</id> <email>test4@gmail.com</email> </row>
   </MyRoot>
```

any help would be appreciated . I've looked through here and could not find anything  since I am new at this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 4 id,email from [user] where len(email) > 5
for xml raw, elements, ROOT('MyRoot') --columns as elements instead of attributes(default)
```

Comment: It might be worth to note, that the recommended approach is using `PATH` mode. This offers the maximum control over the final XML's structure.